# xcode restore previous build?

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4

I copied and pasted the code of a friend into my xcode C project, ran it to see where he went wrong and then closed it, after i had given him the solution. Unfortunately, i did all that in my own project. I thought everything would be fine, as i didn't save his code into my project, but when i opened my project later, i realized i had permanently replaced my code with his. Is there any option to retrieve mine ?

I tried finding an earlier build/version in xcode and in the folder, where i store everything i do, but nothing about any older versions shows up.

Comment: `Xcode Preferences → Building → Build Options → For Unsaved Files → Always Save`? in this case our sincere condolences go out to the members of the deceased's structs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Xcode menu on top, click preferences, select the locations tab, look at the build location option.